# One to one relation sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I am creating a TODO list. Each user has to have only one TODO list. ( I assume one to one model ).
If I set default value of *todolist* is None for each user, then create a *todolist* - it won't link it to the User. User.todolist will still be null. What should I do to have only one instance of todolist for each user?
My code:

```
class ToDoListBase(BaseModel):
    items: List[ToDoItemCreate] = []
    owner_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    todo: Optional[ToDoListCreate]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Sqlalchemy models:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    todolist = relationship('ToDoList', back_populates='owner', uselist=False)

class ToDoList(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'todolists'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True) 
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    owner = relationship('User', back_populates='todolist')
```

What I expect to get is User where User.todolist = {items: [], owner_id: users.id}
what I get is User.todolist = null

and this is how I create todolist:

```
def get_or_create(self, owner_id: int, db: Session):
    todolist = db.query(ToDoList).filter(ToDoList.owner_id==owner_id).first()
    if not todolist:
        todolist = ToDoList(
            owner_id=owner_id, 
        )
        db.add(todolist)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(todolist)
    return todolist
```

Comment: Add the code that is creating the list, as well as an example of your expected output vs what you get.

Comment: You don't need a 1-to-1 relationship between "User" and "ToDoList". You just need a 1-to-many relationship between "User" and "ToDoItems". The "list" will simply be the ToDoItems that are related to the User (parent). Note that any given User will have only one "to do list".